# Kotlin/JS unable to create bindings for jwt-decode library

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

So, I'm kind of new to Kotlin/JS and I'm trying to create Kotlin bindings for the [jwt-decode](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) library.

Here are the Kotlin bindings I've written:

```kotlin
/**
 * A Kotlin definition for the jwt-decode library's invalid token error class
 */
external class InvalidTokenError : Throwable

/**
 * A Kotlin definition for the jwt-decode library's jwt decode options interface
 */
external interface JwtDecodeOptions {
    var header: Boolean?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
}

/**
 * A Kotlin definition for the jwt-decode library's jwt header interface
 */
external interface JwtHeader {
    var typ: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var alg: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var kid: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
}

/**
 * A Kotlin definition for the jwt-decode library's jwt payload interface
 */
external interface JwtPayload {
    var iss: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var sub: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var aud: dynamic // Array<String> or String
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var exp: Long?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var nbf: Long?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var iat: Long?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var jti: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
}

/**
 * A Kotlin definition for the jwt-decode library's jwt decode function
 */
@JsModule("jwt-decode")
@JsNonModule
external fun <T> jwtDecode(token: String, options: JwtDecodeOptions = definedExternally): T
```

Here's how I've imported the library in my gradle build script:

```kotlin
implementation(npm("jwt-decode", jwtDecodeVersion))
```

This apparently is not correct because when I try to use the library in the following way:

```kotlin
val payload: JwtPayload = try {
    jwtDecode(token)
} catch (exc: InvalidTokenError) {
    console.log(exc.message)
}
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidTokenError is not defined

Using only the function like this:

```kotlin
val payload: JwtPayload = jwtDecode(token)
```

Yields:

> jwtDecode is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to solve the problem.

By looking at the following file of the library, I noticed that it was exporting an object instead of a single function:

```js
import jwtDecode, { InvalidTokenError } from "./index";

const wrapper = jwtDecode;
wrapper.default = jwtDecode;
wrapper.InvalidTokenError = InvalidTokenError;
export default wrapper;
```

Therefore, I made the `@JsModule` and `@JsNonModule` annotations apply to the package instead (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-modules.html#apply-jsmodule-to-packages):

```kotlin
@file:JsModule("jwt-decode")
@file:JsNonModule
```

I also needed to add the following annotation to the definition of the `jwtDecode` function, since it was assigned to the `default` property on the exported object:

```kotlin
@JsName("default")
external fun <T> jwtDecode(token: String, options: JwtDecodeOptions = definedExternally): T
```

Comment: can you share your code snippet on sandbox. I am trying to do the same.